# A certain natural map between Tor functors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Consider the following
[image]

Here $A$ is a flat (commutative, unital) $k$-algebra ($k$ a commutative ring) and $\mu:A\otimes_k A\rightarrow A$ is by $\mu(a\otimes b)=ab$, $\mathcal{M}$ denotes a maximal ideal of $A$. I am asking for a (explicit) description of this "natural map $\theta_n$".

It seems to me that the homomorphism in question is the following (from Bourbaki's algèbre homologique, page 110): *given a morphism of rings $A\rightarrow B$ and $A$-modules $E,F$ then one has a natural map $B\otimes_A\mathrm{Tor}^A(E,F)\rightarrow\mathrm{Tor}^B(E\otimes_A B,B\otimes_A F)$*. So in my case I take $A=A\otimes_k A$, $B=(A\otimes_k A)_{\mu^{-1}(\mathcal{M})}$, $E=A$, $F=M$. Now we have for any $(A,A)$-bimodule $M$ (i.e. $A\otimes A$-module) an isomorphism $M\otimes_{A\otimes A}(A\otimes A)_{\mu^{-1}(\mathcal{M})}=M_{\mu^{-1}(\mathcal{M})}$ as $(A\otimes_k A)_{\mu^{-1}(\mathcal{M})}$-modules. Is there some known isomorphism which allows me to identify this with $M_{\mathcal{M}}$? Because in that case I have what I want.

By the way, by the "classical homology argument" he means that a functorial isomorphism in degree 0 between two universal delta functors extends to functorial isomorphisms in all degrees, isn't it?

Comment: For future readers, this is on page 104 of *Cyclic Homology* by Loday. The context is the proof of the HKR theorem (I knew this reminded me of something).

Comment: How do you define the $(A \otimes A)_\mathcal{M}$ in the map you say you can define? $\mathcal{M} \subset A$, not $A \otimes A$. Are you sure there's not an implicit $\mu^{-1}$ somewhere?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: you are right, it doesn't make sense. but since you read this proof, you could answer this question, can't you?

Comment: I read it a long time ago... I don't remember precisely how this works, and I left my copy of Cyclic Homology at my desk. What did you use to get the last map you mention?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I now gave much more details, do you think I am on the right track?